# In fs.writeFile([option]), how an "options parameter" generally work?

Tags: node.js, fs

I was reading this document about Node.js file system, [`fs.writeFile(filename, data, [options], callback)`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback).
So I noticed that i have seen the [options] pretty often, but never used it for anything. Can someone give me an example? All the cases i had didn't use this option.

Comment: It is optional and it will be used (in general) if you want to change the encoding.

Comment: It tells you, right below it...

Comment: i don't understand it, that's why i'm asking. i saw they said it under it. but can someone give me an example?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm guessing your interested in how an `options` parameter generally works in javascript.

As opposed to *what* the parameters are, which are [stated in the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback):

> - **options** *Object*
>
>   - **encoding** *String* | Null default = 'utf8'
>   - **mode** *Number* default = 438 (aka 0666 in Octal)
>   - **flag** *String* default = 'w'

Generally, the `options` parameter is an object, with properties that are the options you want to modify. So if you wanted to modify two of the options on `fs.writeFile`, you'd add each one as a property to `options`:

```
fs.writeFile(
    "foo.txt",
    "bar",
    {
        encoding: "base64",
        flag: "a"
    },
    function(){ console.log("done!") }
)
```

And if you're confused as to what these three params are used for, [the docs for `fs.open`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback) have everything you need. It includes all the possibilities for `flag`, and a description for `mode`. The `callback` is called once the `writeFile` operation is complete.

Answer (score 39):

For anyone ending up here off a search looking for a flags reference, here it is:

| Flag | Description |
| --- | --- |
| r | Open file for reading. An exception occurs if the file does not exist. |
| r+ | Open file for reading and writing. An exception occurs if the file does not exist. |
| rs | Open file for reading in synchronous mode. |
| rs+ | Open file for reading and writing, asking the OS to open it synchronously. See notes for 'rs' about using this with caution. |
| w | Open file for writing. The file is created (if it does not exist) or truncated (if it exists). |
| wx | Like 'w' but fails if the path exists. |
| w+ | Open file for reading and writing. The file is created (if it does not exist) or truncated (if it exists). |
| wx+ | Like 'w+' but fails if path exists. |
| a | Open file for appending. The file is created if it does not exist. |
| ax | Like 'a' but fails if the path exists. |
| a+ | Open file for reading and appending. The file is created if it does not exist. |
| ax+ | Like 'a+' but fails if the the path exists. |

Answer (score 4):

```
fs.writeFile(filename,data,{flag: "wx"},function(err){
    if(err) throw err
    console.log('Date written to file, ',filename)
})
```

As you can see in the above code snippet, the third parameter is the options/flag. There are optional and used to indicate the behaviour of the file to be opened.

I have passed "wx" as option which indicates, file will open for writing and will be created if it doesn't exist. But it will fail if already exists.

By default "w" is passed as option.

For further reading on different options, [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_file_system.htm)

Answer (score 0):

These are the options.

1. encoding (string or NULL), default value is 'utf8'
2. mode (number), default value is 438 (aka 0666 in Octal)
3. flag (string), default value is 'w'